# Windows 10 doesn't show selections in File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

File explorer in Windows 10 is not showing selections. The screenshot below shows the problem:

[image]

As you can see, **6 items selected**, each of the Visual Studio folders under my Document folder.

Things I've tried:

- I tried turning the "[x] Item checkboxes" on and off
- disabled any tools such as anti-virus, displayfusion
- reboot
- Reset windows theme

No visible changes with any of these...

Going into the task manager and restarting Windows File Explorer solves the issue for a little while.

Comment: Seems related to this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-file-explorer-doesnt-highlight-selected/3b57030f-5e8d-479f-a763-e860397c2016?auth=1

Comment: uhg, marked wrong post, sorry.

Comment: CodeSleuth's solution is elegant and effective: The trick is to toggle on and off High Contrast Mode. You can do this quickly with the global shortcut: Shift+Left Alt+Print Screen Turn on high contrast mode, then press the shortcut again to turn off high contrast mode.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I posted a less-invasive solution to this here https://superuser.com/a/1162807

The trick is to toggle on and off High Contrast Mode. You can do this quickly with the global shortcut:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

Turn on high contrast mode, then press the shortcut again to turn off high contrast mode.

Comment: You sir, are a hero!

Comment: This fixed the problem. Does this need to be done every time?

Comment: Yes this fixes the issue when it happens. I'm not aware of a permanent fix.

Answer (score 6):

As an intermediate answer:

- Restarting Windows File Explorer from the task manager may solve this temporarily.
- Performing a full reboot (bypass [fast-start](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html))

Seem to temporarily solve the issue. And it hasn't returned since.

Comment: Yes, temp fix. For me this occurs after I put PC to sleep.